# How to align 2D UV map for wood slat ceiling

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

Forgive me if this has been answered before, I am trying to align a UV map for a wood slat ceiling as you can see in the bottom image. I have tried aligning the UV map manually by rotating 90d but the slats don't align properly. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a screenshot of your *UV Editor* would help to understand where the problem comes from.

Here is a try, I've unwraped the mesh, aligned the 2 parts and inverted one with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>. The small problem is that the planks may look a bit the same:

[image]

A solution would be to shift the UV a bit, it will work fine if all your planks have about the same width, otherwise they won't align anymore:

[image]